# how to move data from one column to another column's row in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How I start coding to get below output.

| id | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 2 | A2 |
| 3 | A1 |
| 4 | A2 |
| 5 | A1 |
| 6 | A1 |

output should be below.

| id | Column1 | Column1.1 | Column1.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | A1 |  |
| 2 | A2 |  | A2 |
| 3 | A1 | A1 |  |
| 4 | A2 |  | A2 |
| 5 | A1 | A1 |  |
| 6 | A1 | A1 |  |

Comment: What is the logic behind your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression to make it.

```
SELECT id,
       Column1,
       CASE WHEN Column1 = 'A1' THEN Column1 END 'Column1.1',
       CASE WHEN Column1 = 'A2' THEN Column1 END 'Column1.2'
FROM T
```